# array_sum numbers with different comma not equal to zero but long number

Tags: php, array-sum

```
if(array_sum($request->amount) <> 0)
{
    session()->flash('sum_error','sum_error');
    return back();
}
else
    return array_sum($request->amount);
```

everything working fine with numbers like this

```
1
2
2
3
5
7
12
36
```

but when numbers in $request->amount be like this

```
278.75
35.96
-203
-13.92
-97.79
```

i have long numbers

```
-2.8421709430404E-14
```

how could i let array_sum give me zero result on this values 
thanks

Comment: that's floating point precision limitations. Do something like `abs(array_sum($request->amount)) < 1e-3`
setting tolerance to 0.001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sprintf to convert exponential formats to your desired ones.

```
$sum = array_sum($request->amount);

$sum = sprintf('%f', $sum);

// or (if you want to limit the number of fractional digits to lets say 6
$sum = sprintf('%.6f', $sum);

// or use number_format function
$sum = number_format($sum,5);

if($sum <> 0)
{
    session()->flash('sum_error','sum_error');
    return back();
}
else
    return $sum;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cast your array sum to integer that will give you output as zero for exponential value

Try below solution:

```
if((int) array_sum($request->amount) <> 0)
{
    session()->flash('sum_error','sum_error');
    return back();
}
else
    return (int) array_sum($request->amount);
```

I have simple cast to integer value

Comment: And what if the sum is 0.45; it is a genuine sum value and it will cause the logic to fail